# PHP Add elements to array

Tags: php

The line below commented `GOAL` creates an error. The error is not displayed (just get a white screen) and I do not have access to php.ini to change the settings. I'm quite sure the error is something along the lines of "can not use [] for reading".

How can I get around this? The keys must be preserved and that doesn't seem possible with array_push.

```
foreach ($invention_values as $value)
        {
            if( array_key_exists($value->field_name, $array) )
            {
                //GOAL but creates error: $array[$value->field_name][] = $value->field_value;
                //works but only with numeric keys
                array_push($array, $value);             
            }

            else $array[$value->field_name] = $value;           
        }
```

EDIT: code

EDIT2: Actually I think the error is cause I'm dealing with an object an not an array. What is the object equivalent of

```
$array[$value->field_name][] = $value ?
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What do you want $array to look like at the end?  It looks like you are trying to make a 2 dimensional array for no reason.

Comment: You can enable error reporting by calling `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Why are you doing `$array[$value->field_name][$value->field_value] = $value->field_value;` maybe it should be `$array[$value->field_name] = $value->field_value;`. What's your intention here?

Comment: @J0HN actually it should be $array[$value->field_name][] = $value->field_value;

Comment: If `$array[$value->field_name]` should be an object - than it's up to you to implement adding logic. Tricks like `$object = (object)$array` and `$array = (array)$object` also might help.

Comment: And still, it's completely unclaer, what are you trying to do with htat code. Maybe your aim can be achieved with a much simpler code, so, please, post the final aim of that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$array[$value->field_name]` is empty, so you can't use `[]` on it. To initialize it as an array, you have to do the following:

```
if(!array_key_exists($value->field_name, $array) ){
    $array[$value->field_name] = array();
}
$array[$value->field_name][] = $value->field_value;
```

It contradicts with what you have in your last line, so you have to decide, do you want `$array[$value->field_name]` be an array or scalar value.